# Debug Toolbar not showing

Tags: python, django, debugging, toolbar

- I installed: pip install django-debug-toolbar
- I have DEBUG=True in my settings
- I have django.contrib.staticfiles and debug_toolbar in INSTALLED_APPS
- i have STATIC_URL = '/static/' in STATIC_URL
- I have 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' high up in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
- I have INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1'] in my settings
- I have urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('**debug**/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
  ]
  and Import debug_toolbar in URLConfig of project.
- I have run python manage.py collectstatic and Debug Toolbar not showing in my browser
  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included this setting in `settings.py`

#settings.py

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "DISABLE_PANELS": ["debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel"],
    "SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT": True,
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": "app_name.small_utils.show_toolbar_callback", # this is the location of the function show_toolbar_callback
}
```

#app_name/small_utils.py

```
def show_toolbar_callback(request):
    return not request.is_ajax() and request.user and request.user.is_superuser
```

After setting this your debug toolbar will start working.

Comment: Note that since Django 3.1 the method `request.is_ajax()` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Using Django 3.1 with django-debug-toolbar with this snippet results in a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether it works on admin area The view template html code on frontend should be valid boilerplate.
For example debug bar shows for this page

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

But for this html template it doesn't work:

```
  <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```